# rails activerecord custom column as foreign/primary key

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have two tables:

manufacturers and products

Both tables have a column "signature" which is unique.

manufacturer model:

```
class Manufacturer < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :products, foreign_key: 'signature', primary_key: 'signature'
end
```

product model:

```
class Product < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :manufacturer, foreign_key: 'signature', primary_key: 'signature'
end
```

In my products index view I'd like to display the value of column 'active' from table manufacturer.

```
# products/index.html.erb
<% @products.each do |product| %>
  <%= product.manufacturer.active %>
<% end %>
```

I'm getting the error

> undefined method `active' for nil:NilClass

How can I access the active attribute of manufacturer model from products index view? I suppose

> product.manufacturer.active

isn't the right way.

Comment: Can you show your controller?

Comment: I use standard controller generated by rails new ...

Comment: What value you get in @manufacturers variable ?

Comment: @Vishal I bet `@manifacturers` is empty since he uses the standard controlller. So he only has `@products` available.

Comment: Does every product have a manifacturer assigned? To implement with a fail save you could use `product.manufacturer&.active`

Comment: @DennyMueller oh, wow, it works! Can you provide this as an answer so I can accept it? thank you very much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your code example you have to make sure that every `product` has an `manufacturer`. Else `.active` would fail on a `manufacturer = nil`.

As a fail save if there are products without manufacturer you can use the Safe Navigation Operator `&.` as mentioned [here](https://bugs.ruby-lang.org/issues/11537) Available from `ruby2.3`

`product.manufacturer&.active`

As an alternative you could make the `.active` call conditionally like

`product.manufacturer.active unless manufactuer.nil?`

or

`product.manufacturer.active if manufactuer`